# How to convert kendoeditor data to pdf itextsharp c#?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Convert Kendo editor data from pdf itextsharp .

```
 public void CommentsByTeachers(CustomMainQuestionDTO feedBackFormnDTO, Font fontH2, Document doc, ref PdfPCell cell1, ref PdfPTable table)
    {
        table = new PdfPTable(1);
       TeachersComment="<ol><li style="text-align:center;list-style-position:inside;"><span style="color:#cc3333;background-color:#ff9999;"><strong><em>Test datadsgtfdyrtyrtutyu</em></strong></span></li><li style="text-align:center;list-style-position:inside;"><strong><em>Dtryut</em></strong></li><li style="text-align:center;list-style-position:inside;"><strong><em>Reytuiyo\</em></strong></li><li style="text-align:center;list-style-position:inside;"><strong><em>Dfghyfrtytyui</em></strong></li><li style="text-align:center;list-style-position:inside;"><strong><em>Vvc</em></strong></li><li style="text-align:center;list-style-position:inside;"><strong><em>Fdhfgjghjgh</em></strong></li><li style="text-align:center;list-style-position:inside;"><strong><em>Fdgfhfgj</em></strong></li><li style="text-align:center;list-style-position:inside;"><strong><em>ghjghjh</em></strong></li><li></li></ol><ul></ul><p>&nbsp;</p><p><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"/>"
        table.LockedWidth = true;
        Chunk Teachers= new Chunk("Hi", fontH2);

        Phrase pharse1 = new Phrase();
        pharse1.Add(Teachers);
        pharse1.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        Paragraph Suggestions = new Paragraph();
        Suggestions .Alignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED_ALL;
        Suggestions .Alignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;
        Suggestions = HtmlParseToString(TeachersComment, Suggestions );

        pharse1.Add(Suggestions );

        cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(pharse1));
        cell1.BorderWidth = 0;
        cell1.Padding = 0;
        cell1.NoWrap = false;
        cell1.SetLeading(1f, 1.3f);
        cell1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        cell1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;
        table.AddCell(cell1);
        doc.Add(table);
    }
 public Paragraph HtmlParseToString(string HTMLString, Paragraph paragraph)
    {
        string HTMLStringData = HTMLString;
        if (HTMLStringData == null)
        {
            HTMLStringData = "No Data Provided!";
        }
        List<IElement> htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(HTMLStringData), null);
        foreach (object item in htmlarraylist)
        {
            paragraph.Add((IElement)item);
        }
        paragraph = HTMLString;
        return paragraph;

    }
```

I need to parse the database value of kendo().editor and write in itextsharp. BUt i cannot parse
Downloaded document not supporting the Font,Background color,Image,Italic(Italic text not showing with proper space alignment),Strikethrough,Center text,Justify,Align text right,Insert ordered list,Insert unordered list and Paragraph.
How i can parse the data

Comment: Please do not use `HTMLWorker`. It is deprecated, obsolete, not maintained, unsupported. Use iText 7.1.0 + pdfHTML 2.0.0 instead.

Comment: can you give a example of it

Comment: Sure I can! See https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml